# Blender VSE proxy not syncing with full render resolution

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a problem where proxy is not synced with the video. When I create 50% quality proxy with any timecode selected, the proxy is incorrectly synced. I have tried it with AV-sync and without. Clip is recorded with OBS, mp4 format and 25fps. How can I sync the proxy with video clip?

I have tried blender versions 2.79 and 2.78c.

This is how it look's like with the proxy (50%).
[image: This is how it look's like with the proxy (50%).]

And rendered in full resolution at the same frame.
[image: And rendered in full resolution at the same frame.]

Comment: First make sure that the original footage is not recorded using any form of variable frame rate. Blender cannot deal with it correctly.

Comment: I have set OBS to record with 25fps and blender is set to 25fps. Also frame rate seems to not change during recording in OBS.